# How to get sum of groups within another groups using pandas GroupBy?

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have this MultiIndexed DataFrame:

`-                             metric_1
cat_A   date         cat_B
foo     2019-03-18   blue             1
                     yellow           2
                     red              3
        2019-03-19   blue             5
                     red             10
                     green            5
bar     2019-03-18   yellow           2
                     black            2
                     red              2
        2019-03-19   red              1
                     blue             8
                     black            1`

I want to create a `metric_2` that takes `metric_1` alone and divides by the total sum of `metric_1` for all `cat_B` within a specific date AND within the respective `cat_A`.

Example of output:

`-                             metric_1   metric_2
cat_A   date         cat_B

foo     2019-03-18   blue             1      0.166
                     yellow           2      0.333
                     red              3      0.500
        2019-03-19   blue             5      0.250
                     red             10      0.500
                     green            5      0.250
bar     2019-03-18   yellow           2      0.333
                     black            2      0.333
                     red              2      0.333
        2019-03-19   red              1      0.100
                     blue             8      0.800
                     black            1      0.100`

I'm trying to sum the levels using `sum(level = 0)`, `sum(level = 1)` and so on, but it takes only the sum of the whole level and I guess I'm missing something.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `reindex`

```
df['New']=df['metric_1']/df['metric_1'].sum(level=[0,1],axis=0).reindex(df.index)
```

Comment: I think no need for `.reindex` since it should align on the indices when assigning it back?

Comment: @ALollz nope since it is multiple index , pandas do not let us join them

Comment: That's odd, it seems to align correctly for me without the reindex call, even though the operation to the right is not in the same order as the original.

Comment: @Wen-Ben, that helped a lot, thanks. Could you give a deeper explanation on why this works? When I try to sum using more than one level like `sum(level=[0,1])` pandas throws a `NotImplementedError: merging with more than one level overlap on a multi-index is not implemented`. But using the reindex after the code works.

Comment: @ViníciusAlcântara I feel like you can find more info in https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/15417